# CSS Width stranege beahviour on small screens

Tags: html, css, width

I have a aparently an easy problem with the width of my container when accesing in mobile devices or small screens

I spent 3 hours wonder why but...I can´t find the way

this is the url >> http://goo.gl/ZlLn3

You can see how the header, the content and the footer are beign limited when accesed by ipad/iphone or you resize the browser in desktop...i don´t need to go responsive, I only want the design shows full in every device !

Comment: give your body a min-width of 950px - it should fix the problem

Comment: oh...this seems to solve partially the issue...but create much more problems than solutions...

this is how looks like now >> http://goo.gl/ZlLn3

Answer (score 0):

Try to use CSS media query

[Target iPhone and iPad with CSS3 Media Queries](http://perishablepress.com/target-iphone-and-ipad-with-css3-media-queries/)

[Media Queries for Standard Devices](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/)

Comment: There is no way to present the whole web in one view with no MQ ?

Answer (score 0):

It is caused by your combination of `width: 100%` and `overflow: hidden`.

The elements are not wider then the browser viewport (100%), and from they they overflow and you hide them ;)

Comment: mmmm I haven´t any overflow hidden in the main containers, neither in the body :$